# Unmodified SwiftUI / Core Data default app code does not run in simulator?

Tags: xcode, core-data, swiftui

When I create and run a new, unmodified, Core Data / SwiftUI app project in Xcode (12.3), the simulator shows a blank screen. Code below.

Upon creation of the new app project, SwiftUI code is generated that includes a *List* along with *Add* and *Edit* buttons. The UI displays correctly in Xcode's preview but not in the simulator.

This is the default code in the `ContentView.swift` file:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
        }
        .toolbar {
            #if os(iOS)
            EditButton()
            #endif

            Button(action: addItem) {
                Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
            }
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this...
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this...
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

You can reproduce this simply by creating a new iOS App project with SwiftUI and Core Data enabled:

[image: xcode]

*Trying to wrap my head around this stuff. Getting stuck on the default code is not promising!*

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65171718/12299030?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I searched and couldn't come up with anything. Anyway, I'd like to leave my question here as it has sample code (the other question explains the situation but does not provide code). Code might be helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO Yes this seems like a bug with the example, might be worth submitting with a feedback

## Problem:

- Since the view is not inside the navigation view the navigation buttons are not visible
- The tool bar modifier requires to use the `ToolbarItem` which is missing.

## Overview:

1. Please wrap the view contents inside a `NavigationView`
2. Wrap the tool bar buttons inside `ToolbarItem`

## Solution:

Replace the body computed property as follows:

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                
                #if os(iOS)
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    
                    EditButton()
                }
                #endif
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {

                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that did it! Thank you. It's really frustrating for a newbie like me trying to wrap my head around this stuff, to be met with a problem right out of the box.

Comment: @Sam In case you were using `CloudKit` sample code, there is a small bug that causes the code not to be synced in realtime. Please add the following code to `Persistence.swift` initialiser `container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true`

Comment: What does that do? Your answer seems to have solved it.

Comment: The viewContext's parent is the persistent store. What is happening is the data is actually synced properly to the device and it is in the persistent  store (SQLite DB), but the viewContext doesn't pick the change from the parent. If you want the context to pick the changes from the parent automatically then you need to add that code. It is more of a core data fix.

Comment: Context is like a scratch pad (session) on to which you can make changes, unless you save it doesn't write changes to the parent. Context's parent could be another context or the persistent store (Database file). In a real app there could be multiple contexts and one context could be saving data to the store, while the other context might have an older copy of the store data. In the above code view context is saying please let me know of any changes from the parent and merge it automatically to my context. viewContext is the one on the main thread and is used generally (norm) by the UI.

Comment: That `viewContext` fix is for syncing across devices using same iCloudID in real time